# HTML5 Canvas Support and Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, webview

I need to draw charts in my application. For that i use RGraph ( http://www.rgraph.net/ ) ; it allows to draw interactive charts with Javascript. I put my javascript code in a HTML document in assets of application, and i call it from a fragment in a ViewPager.

Here is the HTML and javascript code :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<html>
<head>    
    <script src="./libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
    <script src="./libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js" ></script>
    <script src="./libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js" ></script>
    <script src="./libraries/RGraph.common.effects.js" ></script>
    <script src="./libraries/RGraph.pie.js" ></script>
    </head>
<body background="../transparent.png"> 

    <canvas id="cvs" width="420" height="400">[No canvas support]</canvas>
           
    <script>
    
        function CreateGradient (obj, color)
        {
            return RGraph.RadialGradient(obj, 200, 150, 95, 200, 150, 125, color, color)
        }
        
        function isCanvasSupported(){
            var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var canvascheck=(test_canvas.getContext) ? true : false ;           
          return canvascheck;
        }
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            if(isCanvasSupported)
               DrawPieChart();
            else
               document.write("hheheheheh");
        }
        
        
        function DrawPieChart ()
        {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var pie = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', [2,3,6,7,82]);
            pie.Set('chart.colors', [
                                     CreateGradient(pie, '#580600'),
                                     CreateGradient(pie, '#AEAEAE'),
                                     CreateGradient(pie, '#860100'),
                                     CreateGradient(pie, '#C7C7C7'),
                                     CreateGradient(pie, '#A70000')
                                    ]);
            pie.Set('chart.labels.sticks', true);
            pie.Set('chart.labels.sticks.length', 5);
            pie.Set('chart.tooltips', ['Autres',
            'Italie',
            'Royaume-Uni',
            'Espagne',
            'France']);
            pie.Set('chart.labels', ['2%','3%','6%','7%','82%']);
            pie.Set('chart.radius', 150);
            pie.Set('chart.shadow', true);
            pie.Set('chart.shadow.offsetx', 0);
            pie.Set('chart.shadow.offsety', 0);
            pie.Set('chart.shadow.blur', 25);
            pie.Draw();        
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of a fragment :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mWebView = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.group_fragment_one_webView);
        mWebView.setFocusable(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graphs/graph1.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(24);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

        String TAG = "HTML 5";
        WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            try {
                Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m2 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m3 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

                Method m4 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[]{Long.TYPE});
                m4.invoke(ws, 1024*1024*8);

                Method m5 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/cache/");

                Method m6 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Log.d(TAG, "Enabled HTML5-Features");
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }

        }


        mTextView1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.group_fragment_one_textview1);
        mTextView1.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.group_fragment_one_text1));
        Spannable spanSize = new SpannableString(mTextView1.getText());
        spanSize.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f),
                0,
                mTextView1.getText().toString().indexOf("millions"),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        mTextView1.setText(spanSize);
        Spannable colorSpan = new SpannableString(mTextView1.getText());        
        colorSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.red_ribbon)),
                0,
                mTextView1.getText().toString().indexOf("millions"),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mTextView1.setText(colorSpan);
        mTextView1.setTypeface(Utils.getTextFont(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));


        mTextView2 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.group_fragment_one_textview2);
        mTextView2.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.group_fragment_one_text2));
        spanSize = new SpannableString(mTextView2.getText());
        spanSize.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f),
                0,
                mTextView2.getText().toString().indexOf("du chiffre"),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        mTextView2.setText(spanSize);
        colorSpan = new SpannableString(mTextView2.getText());        
        colorSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.red_ribbon)),
                0,
                mTextView2.getText().toString().indexOf("du chiffre"),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mTextView2.setText(colorSpan);
        mTextView2.setTypeface(Utils.getTextFont(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

It works fine on the emulator and on the Eclipse browser... But when I want to see it on a smartphone i have a bug with Canvas. sometimes the chart is correctly displayed, sometimes "No canvas support" is displayed. In the ViewPager, only the fragment n, the fragment n-1 and n+1 are simultaneously instantiated. Other fragments are instantiated when the user scroll on another fragment. So each time the user scroll, a HTML is loaded. and sometimes the canvas is supported, sometimes not...

I tried to get the support of canvas in javascript, but it always returns that the canvas is supported whereas it's not true...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to load the webview on the onResume() method:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graphs/graph1.html");
    super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Worked for me too, I also cleared cache in `onPause()`